# save powerpoint shape add in

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

I am having a look at getting selected shapes from powerpoint slide and If possible save them. Getting the shape part is fine and works okay, but have not had any luck with trying to saving a shape or serializing it and saving.

Has anyone here done something similar before.

```
Slide currentSlide = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide;
              if (currentSlide != null)
              {
                var selection=  Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection;

                if (selection.ShapeRange != null)
                {
                    var shapecount = selection.ShapeRange.Count;

                    if (shapecount > 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 1; i <= shapecount; i++)
                        {
                            var shape = selection.ShapeRange[i];

                            //want to serialize shape object and save it for later use.
                        }
                    }
                }

              }
```

Comment: I don't see any code for saving/serializing shapes in the code. What code did you try to usу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Shape class doesn't provide any methods for serializing. You need to save property values in appropriate format (JSON, XML and etc.). So later you can create a new shape and set up properties according to the file content.

Answer (score 1):

There is no serializing support for shapes, so either you read all the properties and save them as needed or you could just create a repository PPTX to store all the shapes you wish to save.